# Redirect back to original url

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I'm developing a travel web app using nodeJs Express and Passport-local.
Using following function to protect my routes.

how to redirect to original request url

```
function isLoogedin(req, resp,  next){
  If(isAuthenticated()){
    Next()
  }else {
    resp.redirect('/login')
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to redirect, to the `referrer`? because `originalUrl` in express is the same `url` you're requesting, that will cause a redirect loop.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to redirect to the *previous* URL?

Comment: I'm sending url in email,  that url is protected,  and wanted to redirected to that after login

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,  i found solution by saving requested path in session and setting redirect to that followed by deleting from session.

```
function isLoggedIn(req, resp, next) {if(req.isAuthenticated()){next()}else{req.session.returnTo =req.path; resp.redirect("/login")}}
```

And in login router used as following

```
route.post(passport.authenticate('mylonginstrategy'), (req, resp) { resp.redirect(req.session.returnTo || '/') delete req.session.returnTo;}
```